# Obtain 3D point of a ViewPort3d

Tags: c#, xaml, 3d, kinect, viewport3d

I need to obtain the 3D coordinates of one point (X,Y,Z) of an image given by Kinect. I explain it better: I have a 3D image on a ViewPort3D and I want to recieve the X,Y,Z coordinates of one point that I select with the left click of my mouse on the viewPort3D.

Now all I obtain are the X,Y coordinates of the mouse position relative to viewPort3D coordinates, for example, if I select the center of the viewPort3D I recieve "60,60" (the viewPort3D have 120x120 dimensions, for example), but I want to have the real 3D coordinates respect the 3D image I recieve from the Kinect, that could be "43, 23, 80" for example.

How can I do it? I was trying a lot of things during one month but I don't have any result, only the coordinates relative to the viewPort3D.

Thanks!

Here is an image of what I see from my Kinect, I want to click on one pink point with my mouse and get the X,Y,Z coordinates of that point.

[image]

Comment: What are you displaying on the ViewPort3D? Is it the output from Kinect's depth or RGB images, is it some reconstruction of a captured scene, or is it a 3D object created by yourself? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I put an screenshot on my question, what can you tell me? thanks! :)

Comment: I'm sorry dude, I thought you were working with a depth image or something like that... this is a reconstruction of a 3D object created with Kinect Fusion.. I have never worked with that :( I once (long ago) read something on how to determine the 3D point where you are clicking with OpenGL, but I don't know if the Viewport3D might have a function to ease that task.